# Why does hiding the Finder toolbar cause so many side effects?

Tags: macos, finder

I'm on Yosemite, and I'd like to hide the Finder toolbar. But doing "View > Hide Toolbar" causes two undesired side effects:

- Tab functionality is disabled: "File > New Tab" is grayed out. If there are already multiple tabs, then "View > Hide Toolbar" is grayed out. So we can hide the toolbar, or we can have tabs, but not both. I have been able to work around this issue by installing [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) and using its tab functionality.
- Folders open in new windows, instead of the same window. This behavior is [actually documented](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19060?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US). We can revert to the regular behavior with various key combinations, depending on how we're opening the folders, for example by using Ctrl+Cmd+O instead of just Cmd+O. This is not a great solution, though -- I don't want to have to use more complicated keyboard shortcuts just to get Finder to behave normally.

My questions:

- Are there better workarounds to get Finder to behave normally when the toolbar is hidden?
- What possible reasons could there be to have Finder behave this way? It seems like "the principle of most surprise" at work.

Answer (score 2):

As to your second question of "why does the Finder behave this way?", I will hazard a guess that it mimics the decades-long traditional behavior of Finder windows.  This was how Finder windows worked in Mac OS through version 9.

[image: Mac OS 9 Finder windows]

In earlier versions of OS X, there was a button in the top right corner of windows that toggled between the "old" Finder window behavior and the "new" (toolbar) behavior.

[image: OS X Finder window top right button]

The button was removed in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, but you get the same results by hiding the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, I remember the proliferating windows from Macintoshes past. It seems extremely odd, though, to make the choice of old or new behavior follow the visibility of the toolbar, rather than, say, a preferences checkbox.