# Hide the Finder toolbar, but show the sidebar

Tags: finder

It seems that the sidebar is automatically hidden (and the menubar option to show it becomes greyed-out) when the toolbar is hidden on Mojave 10.14. Is there a way to hide Finder's toolbar **while keeping the sidebar visible**?

---

More context: I constantly use the sidebar but never, ever use the toolbar. I want as much free screen space as possible. All the toolbar actions I use are more easily accessible with the keyboard:

- <kbd>Cmd + Up</kbd> to go *up* to the parent folder,
- <kbd>Cmd + F</kbd> to search / *Find*,
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>4</kbd> for view modes,
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> to navigate history backward/forward,
- <kbd>Cmd + I</kbd> to open detailed file *Information*,
- <kbd>Cmd + Shift + G</kbd> to *Go* to a specific file path.

Related question on different behaviours caused by the toolbar's opened/closed state: [Why does hiding the Finder toolbar cause so many side effects?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201115/why-does-hiding-the-finder-toolbar-cause-so-many-side-effects)

Comment: I consider this to be one of the *many* things simply forgotten about for so long people forget why it was first done. Notice it also lifts the "n of nn selected, nnn GB available" to the top too.